# Is it more performant to use the dependencies of a React `useCallback` hook as arguments of the callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Suppose I have a callback function in React which uses variables `a`, `b`, and `c`.  I want to know the best way to make use of the `useCallback` hook.

I can create a callback which takes no arguments and use `[a,b,c]` as the dependencies array.

```
const onMutate = useCallback( () => {~~~~} , [a,b,c] )
~~~~ onPress={onMutate}
```

Or I can create a callback which takes arguments `(a,b,c)` and has an empty dependency array.

```
const onMutate = useCallback( (a,b,c) => { ~~~~} , [] )
~~~~ onPress={() => onMutate(a,b,c)}
```

In the former, the callback function is newly created each time, but there is no anonymous function in onPress.

In the latter, the callback function is created only once, but an anonymous function is created in onPress each time.

Which case is better?

Comment: I would say the first one because it will stop further re-renders of the component with the `onPress` property.

Comment: Why is the `callback function is newly created each time`? Isn't it just when `a, b, c` change?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it took me a minute to process what you said but you are totally right.

Comment: There is a note in docs for using "arrow functions as event handler". [If this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering.](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

First keep in mind: Using `useCallback` is not always a good case, [as Kent C. Dodds says](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback).

However, if you really wanna go with `useCallback` it also only makes sense, when the value in `useCallback` is memoized. See this one CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-dawn-glqlg

---

That being said, if you are sure to use `useCallback` it doesn't matter, which way you are going, because in the very best case, all three of those variables are being memoized in the first run.

Comment: The question contains two variants: The first can make sense sometimes; The second one does not make any sense at all. Because the `onPress` will always be assigned a new function instance. The whole idea of `useCallback` is to keep the function instance the same identity. I find further fault in: Your code sandbox points to nothing. And your statements about momoization is completely unclear. So as it is now I don't think its a good answer. But I appreciate the link to Kent Dodd's good article.